# PHP json_encode() array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want a json with this format :

```
{"dernierNumeroDEVIS":[{"numero_devis":"48"}]}
```

But I have this :

```
{"dernierNumeroDEVIS":{"numero_devis":"48"}}
```

My PHP :

```
    $array = [
        "numero_devis" => "0"
    ];
    $arrayDevis = array ('dernierNumeroDEVIS' => $array );
    echo json_encode($arrayDevis);
```

Comment: `array ('dernierNumeroDEVIS' => $array )` -> `array ('dernierNumeroDEVIS' => [$array] )`

Comment: ___Break out the Garlic___, all the vampires are decending on this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your array in an array

```
$array = [
    "numero_devis" => "0"
];
$arrayDevis = array ('dernierNumeroDEVIS' => [$array]);
echo json_encode($arrayDevis);
```

To avoid confusion perhaps it'll be easier to understand if you used standard objects and arrays in PHP as they will be the same when formatted as JSON.

```
$obj = new \stdClass();
$obj->numero_devis = 0;
$obj2 = new \stdClass();
$obj2->dernierNumeroDEVIS = [
    $obj,
];
echo json_encode($obj2);
```

Comment: I do like a person thats not afraid of `stdClass()` and does not try to do everything with arrays UV

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need two dimensional array

```
$array = array("numero_devis" => "0");
$arrayDevis = array ('dernierNumeroDEVIS' => array($array) );
echo json_encode($arrayDevis);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [];
$array['dernierNumeroDEVIS'][] = ['numero_devis'=>48];
echo json_encode($array);
```

**Output:**

```
{"dernierNumeroDEVIS":[{"numero_devis":"48"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need it this way but here you go ...

```
$array = [
    array(
        "numero_devis" => "0",
     )
];
$arrayDevis = array ('dernierNumeroDEVIS' => $array );
echo json_encode($arrayDevis);
```

**Result:**

```
{"dernierNumeroDEVIS":[{"numero_devis":"0"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is an array inside the array something like that:

```
$array = array(array("numero_devis"=>"0"));             
$arrayDevis = array('dernierNumeroDEVIS' => $array );
echo json_encode($arrayDevis);
```

Output:

{"dernierNumeroDEVIS":[{"numero_devis":"0"}]}

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else hasn't already said, you need to wrap your array inside another array, like this:

```
array ('dernierNumeroDEVIS' => [$array] )
```

Heh.

Comment: Hahahah Love a sence of humour